# issues with iphone 5 optimization

Tags: ios, ios6, iphone-5

I'm trying to make my views in my app compatible with the iPhone 5. My storyboard is currently not using autolayout, and when I run it on the iphone 5 simulator or an actual device, all of the backgrounds stretch to fit the screen except for two of them, one of which was set up the same as all of the others that stretch and one of which has an AVVideoPreviewLayer on it. The two that don't stretch have white space on the right side. The ones that do stretch have the backgrounds stretched but the buttons all remain in the place where they would be on a retina 3.5 screen, i.e. shifted over to the left. If I enable autolayout, the buttons all snap to the correct positions but now none of the backgrounds stretch, both the ones that wouldn't stretch before as well as the ones that did.

I haven't been able to find much good information on optimizing the apps for iphone 5. The 4 inch retina launch image is in place in the app summary. If anybody could give me some guidance or point me towards a good resource for figuring this out, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up making the most sense for me just to have two storyboards, because there were enough differences that doing anything else would have been way too difficult, if not outright impossible. I just threw this in my app delegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
    UIStoryboard *storyBoard;

    CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    result = CGSizeMake(result.width * scale, result.height * scale);

    if(result.height == 1136){
        storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone5" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *initViewController = [storyBoard instantiateInitialViewController];
        [self.window setRootViewController:initViewController];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set some **NSConstraints** when you enable **Autolayout** you should enable some rules for the backgrounds like "**Top Space To Superview**" and "**Bottom Space To Superview**" and **Width** fixed to the **Superview** for example.

So the main idea is to establish some rules for the Objects in the Storyboard`

Comment: When I enable autolayout the background constraints already have "Top Space To Superview" and "Bottom Space To Superview". I don't see where to fix the width to the superview though, all I see for width is to set the pixel count, which is currently 480 by 320 and I assume what is throwing it off. Where would I fix the width to the superview?

Comment: You can override those contrains and set your own. If you set **Top Space to Superview** and **Bottom Space to Superview** you must edit the **height constraint** to **Greater Than 480** if you see the **iPhone 4** or **Less Than 568** if you see the **iPhone 5** , that's how the image will scale according with the screen.

Comment: And you might have to set one of the Top Space to Superview / Bottom Space to Superview  to the same Greater/Less . And you must keep the viewcontroller as **Inferred** . It would be much easier to show than explain.

Comment: Is this something I have to do programatically then? I don't see any way to change the height constraint to be different according to device in the size inspector in the storyboard.

Comment: Nope , you can set the constraint from the storyboard but some of the others must match, it's difficult like this, if I could've seen the project it could be much easier.